# Matlab. Integration with a changing parameter

Tags: matlab

I am doing a little script in Matlab using the numerical integration subroutine in matlab

Im am having som problems with the dimensions of the variables:

I need to integrate from o to pi/2 the product of the Moment Generating function of a fading with another function given:

```
mgf= (2*(sin(phi)).^2)/(2*(sin(phi)).^2+ EbNolin.*b);
```

the other function is:

```
function = -b./(2*((sin(phi)).^2))
```

where b is a constant:

the thing is that EbNolin is a vector that changes for every value as:

```
EbNodB = [0:0.51:40];
EbNolin = 10.^(EbNodB/10) ;
```

So to make the integral i have defined:

```
phi =0:0.02:pi/2;
```

To get the same length of EbNolin and phi, but when i try to integrate there are many errors, i have tried:

```
for i = 1:(79),

Pe = [Pe (a/pi).*quadgk(mgf(i)*function),phi,0,pi/2] %using quadgk
Pe = [Pe (a/pi).*integrate(mgf(i)*function),phi,0,pi/2] %using integrate
Pe = [Pe (a/pi).*int(mgf(i)*function),phi,0,pi/2] %using int
```

But there are always something... I dont know if i am on the good way doing the integral into a loop, but i dont know how to do it in other way.
My matlab version is r2010

I would be so happy if somebody can give me a little help, merci !

Answer (score 0):

try calculating mgf like this:

```
mgf= (2*(sin(phi)).^2)./(2*(sin(phi)).^2+ EbNolin.*b);
```

also keep in mind that instead of :

```
EbNodB = [0:0.51:40];
phi =0:0.02:pi/2;
```

you can use:

```
EbNodB = linspace(0, 40, 79);
phi = linspace(0, pi/2, 79) ;
```